# MongoDB version 4.2 get field value from aggregation function that isn't one of the aggregation fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with documents that has the following fields: Name,Date,City,Value
I created an aggregation where the group by is on the Name for getting the max(date).
From the results I need the field Value (but as you can see this field isn't in the aggregation so I don't really know how can I get it).

```
db.direct_client.aggregate([ 
{
    $group : {
       _id : {"name":"$name"},
       count: { $sum: 1 },
       max_date:{$max:"$created_date"}
    }
}
])
```

Can someone guide me how to get this data

Comment: See answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615854/mongo-aggregation-field-x-with-max-y

Comment: the group of a specific name, will have many Value , if you just need to take any value, from them you can add to the accumulators `{"value" : {$first: "$value"}}` to take the first one (which is a random one if collection is not sorted)